# VSCode renderIndentGuides stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Where did my VSCode indent guides go?**

As best as I can recall, indent guides were working as advertised in VSCode 1.17.2 on my MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G29)) a few hours ago. Now, with no change to any settings and without closing/reopening the editor, I notice that they're no longer rendering. I checked multiple file formats and none of them work.

I checked `editor.renderIndentGuides`. It's defaulted to `true`, and isn't being forced to `false` anywhere, confirmed by noting that `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration("editor")["renderIndentGuides"]` evaluates to `true`).

One minor oddity I noticed was that the settings editor itself was correctly showing indent guides until I restarted VSCode and now it's broken too.

After noticing the problem, I briefly installed the [Guides](https://github.com/spywhere/vscode-guides) extension to see if it would make things any better. It worked, but I found its appearance slightly too in-your-face and didn't need any of the special bits (in which case the Guides README recommends not to use it) so I removed it, after which guides are again not rendering. If nothing else works, I'll reinstall Guides and see if I can tweak it to suit, but I'd rather just have VSCode work as intended.

I narrowed the problem down slightly to the MBP's built-in retina display. When I run on a non-retina external screen, I see the guides. However, even there, I noticed that playing with indentation level settings causes the guides to break up a little and I have to close and reopen the file to restore order.

Comment: Did Guides leave behind any settings?

Comment: No, and just to be clear, I only installed Guides after I noticed the problem, in order to see if it would offer a decent workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the proximate cause. Setting the font too small (< 12pt) produces aliasing on thin (presumably 1-pixel) lines.

A non-retina external screen exhibits similar behaviour, though it requires smaller fonts. Also, while both screens have trouble with rulers, only the retina screen loses the guides.